# MXBean already registered with name spring.application (Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0)

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

When re-deploying a Spring application (which uses a Postgres db) in CloudFoundry, the application now fails with the following Stacktrace. Any help is appreciated.

**Here is the output of the cf push command:**

```
-----> _Downloaded app package (46M)
-----> _Downloaded app buildpack cache (97M)
    -----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.0 
-----> _Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_60 
-----> _Downloading Spring Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE 
       Modifying /WEB-INF/web.xml for Auto Reconfiguration
-----> Downloading Tomcat Instance 8.0.24 
       Expanding Tomcat to .java-buildpack/tomcat (0.1s)
-----> Downloading Tomcat Lifecycle Support 2.4.0_RELEASE 
-----> Downloading Tomcat Logging Support 2.4.0_RELEASE 
-----> Downloading Tomcat Access Logging Support 2.4.0_RELEASE 
-----> Uploading droplet (97M)
```

**Here is the Stracktrace from the application start**

```
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT [2015-08-20 16:50:06.346]  - ???? [localhost-startStop-1] .... ERROR --- DispatcherServlet: Context initialization failed
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@787bb40b] with key '__cloudDataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name spring.application:type=DataSource,name=dataSource
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name spring.application:type=DataSource,name=dataSource
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.addReference(MXBeanLookup.java:151)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.register(MXBeanSupport.java:160)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.preRegister2(MBeanSupport.java:173)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:930)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:670)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ... 28 more
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  StandardWrapper.Throwable
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@787bb40b] with key '__cloudDataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name spring.application:type=DataSource,name=dataSource
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.34+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name spring.application:type=DataSource,name=dataSource
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.addReference(MXBeanLookup.java:151)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.register(MXBeanSupport.java:160)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.preRegister2(MBeanSupport.java:173)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:930)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:670)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ... 28 more
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  Servlet [spring] in web application [] threw load() exception
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name spring.application:type=DataSource,name=dataSource
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanLookup.addReference(MXBeanLookup.java:151)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.register(MXBeanSupport.java:160)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.preRegister2(MBeanSupport.java:173)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:930)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:670)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.35+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-20T18:50:06.40+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 20,086 ms
2015-08-20T18:50:06.41+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61539"]
2015-08-20T18:50:06.42+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool         INFO    Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015-08-20T18:50:06.43+0200 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Server startup in 20153 ms
```